# React Native Expo - Unable to find a browser on the host to open the inspector

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, debugging, expo

[image]

I am currently getting the error above when I try to open the debugger for my React Native application. I'm testing my build on a real iPhone and am using a development build.

Answer (score 0):

first you should type "chrome://inspect" on the browser.
then you will see a page like this; [expo debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W73CT.png)

then configure your port to localhost:8081 and click the "inspector" button. you can find a good documentation on tihs; https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging?js-debugger=hermes#react-devtools

when you saw the "Opening the Debugger " title, you should swich the tags on the left one;"Hermes Debugger / Expo" .
then you can find very good orientation.